# How to: PHP Mail() with Custom "Mailed-By" Header?

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I used `-f` header as like in `mail($to, $subject, $message, $header, "-fwww.xxxx.com")` but it doesn't actually working out.
Here you can test yourself at my testing page http://arkar.nopayhost.com
I can't actually "change" its "mailed-by: www02.nopayhost.com" line inside emails.
But (at least) '-f' can "remove" its default value "mailed-by: www02.nopayhost.com".

Any other way?

Comment: Have you tried using an email instead of domain, as in: `me@website.com`. A lot of the examples on the web seem to do that.

Comment: @EdoDodo: Do you mean `-fme@website.com` ?

Comment: Yup. According to this forum post, that should work: http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=141569#p141569

Comment: I've just tried EdoDodo, but it doesn't work. As you can test at my page. :(

Answer (score 3):

the

```
"Mailed-By: www.xxxx.com"
```

Does not work !

Use this:

```
 "-f info@yourdomain.com "
```

---

Persian Language:

کد های قبلی کار نکردند و به جای اون ها از کد

```
"-f info@yourdomain.com "
```

استفاده کردم و جواب گرفتم... موفق باشید

Answer (score 1):

try to change

```
"-fwww.xxxx.com"
```

to

```
"Mailed-By: www.xxxx.com"
```

Comment: Ehh, i don't think that simple.

Comment: Um... I don't think that would work. The fifth parameter of the function is extra parameters to pass to `sendmail` and just passing a header wouldn't work.

Comment: @EdoDodo: whoops, thanks. Alvin, that one belongs to fourth parameter, to headers

Answer (score 0):

Just add `"Mailed-By: www.xxxx.com\r\n"` to the beginning of $header. Make sure the line ends with \r\n. You shouldn't need the -f parameter. Post the code you have so far if that isn't working.